# Convert all files in a folder from PDF to PCL with Ghostscript

Tags: pdf, converters, ghostscript, printer-control-language

I'm trying to use Ghostscript to convert my files in PDF to PCL. I'm able to convert one file with this command:

```
gswin64c -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -dSAFER -sDEVICE=pxlcolor -sOutputFile=[PCLPath].pcl [PDFPath].pdf
```

It works fine, I think, if you see anything wrong or not needed please say me.

The question is to convert all files in a folder, I don't know how to change the command line to do that, or what I have to do, maybe a script file??

Other question is if there is someway to accelerate the process, with any options in the command line, or using Linux instead Windows, whatever.

Thanks in advance!

Greetings.

Answer (score 2):

You can use **[Ghostscript Studio](http://ghostscriptstudio.codeplex.com/)** to do that.

See the image below:

[image]

Comment: Great! Maybe it be useful. I notice that you use `%d` in the output filename format to get one page per file...but I want to get one file per file, how I can do that? Thanks!

Comment: Yes, this works if you want to get only one page per file. By default Ghostscript does not support multiple files to multiple files. This can be achieved by writing a batch script to run Ghostscript once per each file. When i find some time today or tomorrow i will extend Ghostscript Studio application to support / automate this.