# Is there anyway in vb.net to print a PDF to a file such as a pcl or postscript?

Tags: c#, vb.net, printing, postscript, printer-control-language

I am trying to write a series of functions to print different file formats to a file rather than directly, I am struggling with PDFs and was wondering if anyone knew of a way to convert or print a PDF to a file (PS, PCL etc.)

Comment: Check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18912469/convert-all-files-in-a-folder-from-pdf-to-pcl-with-ghostscript

Comment: Thanks but ideally need to avoid external libraries

Comment: Want to avoid external libraries? - no problem. Write your own PDF creator/post script writer and be done with that. :o))

Comment: @T.S. its not necessarily a big task if you dont need that many capabilities drawing lines and text is pretty trivial to do. But if you need to support the whole spec then yes its a bit of suicide.

Comment: @joojaa I would better save my time to do something productive than reinvent the bicycle :o)

Comment: @T.S. Well it could be useful if you needed to do pdf inside a browser javascript or some other program with limited toolset/scope. After all my python PDF code was only 100 lines long (windows batch version even shorter). By the way the guys sitting next room to me are actually writing a PHD on redesigning the bike ground up. Like i said its not necessarily that much work.